# python selenium/unittest check whether value has changed

Tags: selenium, python-unittest

How come I get the same results for q1 and q2? It seems that q2 is overwritten by q1. Don't understand since they reference the same element but store its value in different variables at different points of time.

There is definitely a change after I do ic.click for the second time. When I solely run the second part it gives me the correct result.

```
def test_relation(self):
    ic = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='selectNumber']/option[2]")
    ic.click()

    q1 = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@class='quarterSelect form__multiselect']/option")
    print(len(q1))

    ic = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='selectNumber']/option[1]")
    ic.click()

    q2 = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@class='quarterSelect form__multiselect']/option")
    print(len(q2))
```

Comment: Share your HTML.

Comment: First of all, if you post (a part of) the DOM that would be helpfull. Second, if you say that the DOM changes after you perform ic.click(), than it looks like your code ran before the DOM was actually changed due to that click. So you're still executing code against the old DOM. You might want to build in a 'wait'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting ic.click() to cause something to happen, then you need to wait for that change to happen before you can look for it's result.  adding in a call to WebDriverWait().until() for something will probably help you.

Also, I notice that the code is printing len(q1) and len(q2).  are you sure that their length is not the same, even though they may have different items in the list?

Comment: yes, I'm sure about the different length of q1 and q2. But I also face this problem when I try to compare the text values of an element I stored in two different variables at different times. Also I've tried time.sleep() and driver.implicitelywait(). This didn't help. I'll try an explicit wait as you suggested. Thanks!!